# Request.IsAuthenticated and User.Identity.IsAutheticated always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

The code works fine when tested on the local machine. When the project is published to the server, it always returns `false` while checking is authenticated and redirects to login page.

I have used the same code in another project and it is running fine on the same server.

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name),
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, loc),

               //new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role),
               //Added after adding AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier; into global
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, model.UserName)
               }, "ApplicationCookie");

var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

// Set current principal
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
var ctx = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
var authManager = ctx.Authentication;
authManager.SignIn(identity);

return RedirectToAction("Main", "Home");
```

Comment: Not sure about the problem because you haven't shared much context. Just a wild guess, can you try setting `HttpContext.Current.User = claimsPrincipal` along with `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`?

Comment: @RohitVats, the above code works fine in localhost ie it redirects to "Main" action. There it checks if the request is authenticated, if not, it will be redirected to the login page. When published to server, the request authenticated is always returning false.